# Why does my View Posting Null Data to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have List passing  to view from my index controller and it was displayed fine. But when I'm clicking the save to post the data. It doesn't bind the data in my view model. See Img. below

[image]

**Controller - ActionResult Index()**

```
var user = HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

int PatientID = data_Patient.getPatientID(user.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value);

var patientDashboardSetting = db.PatientDashboardSetting.Include(p => p.DashboardContent).Include(p => p.Patient);

PatientDashboardSettingView model = new PatientDashboardSettingView();

model.PatientDashboardSettings = new List<PatientDashboardSetting (patientDashboardSetting);
```

**Saving controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveChanges(PatientDashboardSettingView patientDashboardSettings)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "PatientDashboardSetting");
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class PatientDashboardSettingView
{
   public List<PatientDashboardSetting> PatientDashboardSettings { get; set; }
}
```

**PatientDashboard model**

```
public partial class PatientDashboardSetting
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int PatientID { get; set; }

    public int DashboardContentID { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public bool IsSharable { get; set; }

    public virtual DashboardContent DashboardContent { get; set; }

    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

**View Form**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "PatientDashboardSetting", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.PatientDashboardSettings.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.PatientDashboardSettings[i].ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.PatientDashboardSettings[i].PatientID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.PatientDashboardSettings[i].DashboardContentID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.PatientDashboardSettings[i].IsSharable)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.PatientDashboardSettings[i].IsActive)
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: `modelItem => Model` would be `modelItem => modelItem`, assuming you're trying to use the strongly-typed helper.

Comment: Hi @Tieson T., Thanks for the response. I have tried to use `modelItem => modelItem` code, Unfortunately it still not posting the data in my controller :(  Same with [@y Stoli Suggestion ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57719346/11850048)

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab of your brower's developer tools (activated by pressing F12, normally)? You'd want to verify that you're actually posting data, and that the posted data does not have any missing indexes in the form's keys.

Comment: try to use public ActionResult SaveChanges([FromBody] PatientDashboardSettingView patientDashboardSettings)

Comment: @Tieson T. Yes,I checked the Form data(Under Header tab) that has been submitted, All records are included in the form data.

Comment: I guess I found the solution. I used the Model as list ( not view model) `public ActionResult SaveChanges( List<PatientDashboardSetting> patientDashboardSettings)` to hold the incoming data(yes, I realize that the the return data is a list of **PatientDashboardSetting**). I now getting the list of data from my view. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

try using this in View Form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.PatientDashboardSettings[i].ID)
```

Comment: Hi @y Stroli, Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion, unfortunately, It's still not passing the data to my controller :(

Comment: you wrote in your question: "I have List passing to view from my index controller and it was displayed fine."
May I ask if this is verified (since you're using hidden fields)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I Actually want to hide those elements so I Use HiddenFor. I confirmed that It was in my page, when I use to Inspect the element.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be because when the view is rendered, no values are assigned to the viewModel,

`model.PatientDashboardSettings = new List<PatientDashboardSetting (patientDashboardSetting);`

(I can't see your other lines so I assume so), and as they are hidden values you could not set values before submit, so they should be null, if that's the case, please try to assign some values to the viewModel in your Index() method, and then try submitting again.

Comment: Hi @wen_m, Thanks for the response. The view model has data. this line in controller fill it. `PatientDashboardSettingView model = new PatientDashboardSettingView();
model.PatientDashboardSettings = new List<PatientDashboardSetting (patientDashboardSetting);`   Also I'm using `@model model.PatientDashboardSettingView` and there ara data populated in my view

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass all values from the model type. If one is not in the list of hiddenFor, then nothing till be passed.

Comment: Hi @Steffen, thanks for the response .  I found the solution  by using Model as list ( not view model) `public ActionResult SaveChanges( List<PatientDashboardSetting> patientDashboardSettings)` to hold the incoming data(yes, I realize that the the return data is a list of PatientDashboardSetting). I'm now getting the list of data from my view